# Add cssClass dynamically based on conditions using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 sections in `HTML`. What I want is, I want to add a class called as `completed` dynamically when the controls of first section is filled and when `Next` button is clicked using `jquery`.

Below is my `html`

```html
<section id="siteDetails" class="tabPane first active">
            <h2>Site Details</h2>
            <div class="tabText clearfix">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label>Type of Site <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>                      
                        <select id="ddlSiteType" class="form-control custom-select">
                            <option selected="selected">--Select--</option>
                            <option value="OWN BUILD">OWN BUILD</option>
                            <option value="IP COLO">IP COLO</option>
                            <option value="RCOM COLO">RCOM COLO</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 marginBottom">
                        <label>Site / Plot Dimension (Mtr) (Minimum Required :18W*18D Mtr) Ref attached Plot drawing for reference. <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="txtSitePlotDimension" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Technology <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <select id="ddlTechnolgy" class="form-control custom-select">
                            <option selected="selected">--Select--</option>
                            <option value="SCPC">SCPC</option>
                            <option value="TDMA">TDMA</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Mount Type <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <select id="ddlMountType" class="form-control custom-select">
                            <option selected="selected">--Select--</option>
                            <option value="PM">PM</option>
                            <option value="NPM">NPM</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Antenna Size <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <select id="ddlAntennaSize" class="form-control custom-select">
                            <option selected="selected">--Select--</option>
                            <option value="2.4">2.4</option>
                            <option value="3.8">3.8</option>
                            <option value="7.3">7.3</option>
                            <option value="11.1">11.1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">AMSL(m) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAMSL" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label>Platform required <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="radio" name="Platform" value="YES" id="rbPltYes" />
                                Yes</label>
                            <label class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="radio" name="Platform" value="NO" id="rbPltNo" />
                                No</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label>Platform Height(m) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPlatformHeight" maxlength="10" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label>Rooftop Site  <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="radio" name="Rooftype" value="YES" id="rbRFSYes" />
                                Yes</label>
                            <label class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="radio" name="Rooftype" value="NO" id="rbRFSNo" />
                                No</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label>No of Floors in building</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNoofFloorsBldg" maxlength="10" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" disabled="disabled" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>In addition to standard space requirement for Roof top Site additional space 5 Mtr * 4 Mtr for VSAT Antenna. <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAddRoofTopSite" maxlength="50" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>
                            Structural Stability Certificate (SST)<br class="hidden-sm" />
                            from Local consultant <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" id="txtStructuralStability" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>Height of the Antenna from Ground [Mtrs] <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txthegtAntennaFromGrnd" maxlength="10" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>Satellite Band <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtSatelliteBand" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="antennaOrientation" class="tabPane">
            <h2>Antenna Orientation</h2>
            <div class="tabText clearfix">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>Azimuth Angle </label>
                        <%--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAzimuthAngle" maxlength="50" />--%>

                        <label>GSAT 16 (55° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAzimuth16" maxlength="10" />
                        <br />
                        <label>Azimuth Angle GSAT 18 (74° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAzimuth18" maxlength="10" />
                        <br />
                        <label>Azimuth Angle GSAT 12 (83° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAzimuth12" maxlength="10" />
                        <br />
                        <label>Azimuth Angle GSAT 17 (93.5° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAzimuth17" maxlength="10" />


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>Elevation Angle </label>
                        <%--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtElevationAngle" maxlength="50" />--%>
                        <label>GSAT 16 (55° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtElevation16" maxlength="10" />
                        <br />
                        <label>GSAT 18 (74° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtElevation18" maxlength="10" />
                        <br />
                        <label>GSAT 12 (83° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtElevation12" maxlength="10" />
                        <br />
                        <label>GSAT 17 (93.5° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtElevation17" maxlength="10" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>Distance to nearest airport (KM) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtdistNearAirport" maxlength="10" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>Airport Name <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAirportName" maxlength="50" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>


<div class="formNavigation clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <a class="formbutt prev">Previous</a>
                <a class="formbutt next">Next</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How can I add this using `jquery` or any other way to add the class

**update**

I want to add that class here

```
 <div class="tabList">
        <ul>
            <li class="tab first active" id="SiteDetails"><a rel="#siteDetails" href="#">Site Details</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a rel="#antennaOrientation" href="#">Antenna Orientation</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a rel="#losclearance" href="#">LOS Clearance</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a rel="#cablesandelectrical" href="#">Cables &amp; Electrical</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a rel="#otherdetails" href="#">Other Details</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a rel="#panoramicPhotos" href="#">Panoramic Photos</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a rel="#satelliteLosSnaps" href="#">Satellite LOS Snaps</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a rel="#SitePlotLayout" href="#">Site /Plot Layout</a></li>
            <li class="tab last"><a rel="#SiteFinalizationReport" href="#">Site Finalization Report</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**update 2**

Show hide of tab

```
/*next show and hide*/
$('.next').on('click', function () {
    if ($('.tabList li.active').next().hasClass('last')) {
        $('.formNavigation .next').hide();
        //$('.formNavigation .saveAsDraft, .formNavigation .submit').show();
        $('.tabList li.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        $('.tabContent .tabPane.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.formNavigation .prev').show();
        $('.tabList li.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        $('.tabContent .tabPane.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: how you will navigate to next and previous sections ? You have not written any code for that.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay: i have written that in jquery, do u want to see that ?

Comment: yes please.I want to see.

Comment: `jQuery('.formbutt.next').on('click', function(){ 

if(/* conditional logic to check for completed input fields*/){ 
/* if condition is true */ jQuery('.tabList').addClass('completed');  
} 
});` 


Adding a class to an element when another specified element is clicked is the easy part. The tricky part is applying the conditional logic to check whether all required fields have values before applying the aforementioned class.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay: updated the question, have a look

Comment: I think @Nilesh Khisadiya's answer is what you want.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay: he has not added class and he is checking each section with the name. i want something which is dynamic

Answer (score 1):

You can add class on section `siteDetails` using jQuery `$('#siteDetails').addClass('completed');` OR hide that section by `$('#siteDetails').hide();`.

Please have a look on this solution. Click on `Previous`/`Next` button.

```js
$('#siteDetails').show();
$('#antennaOrientation').hide();
$('.formNavigation .prev').hide();

$('.next').click(function(){
$('#siteDetails').addClass('completed');
$('#siteDetails').hide();
$('#antennaOrientation').show();
$('.formNavigation .next').hide();
$('.formNavigation .prev').show();
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
$('#siteDetails').show();
$('#antennaOrientation').hide();
$('.formNavigation .next').show();
$('.formNavigation .prev').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="siteDetails" class="tabPane first active">
            <h2>Site Details</h2>
            <div class="tabText clearfix">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label>Type of Site <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>                      
                        <select id="ddlSiteType" class="form-control custom-select">
                            <option selected="selected">--Select--</option>
                            <option value="OWN BUILD">OWN BUILD</option>
                            <option value="IP COLO">IP COLO</option>
                            <option value="RCOM COLO">RCOM COLO</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 marginBottom">
                        <label>Site / Plot Dimension (Mtr) (Minimum Required :18W*18D Mtr) Ref attached Plot drawing for reference. <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="txtSitePlotDimension" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Technology <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <select id="ddlTechnolgy" class="form-control custom-select">
                            <option selected="selected">--Select--</option>
                            <option value="SCPC">SCPC</option>
                            <option value="TDMA">TDMA</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Mount Type <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <select id="ddlMountType" class="form-control custom-select">
                            <option selected="selected">--Select--</option>
                            <option value="PM">PM</option>
                            <option value="NPM">NPM</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Antenna Size <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <select id="ddlAntennaSize" class="form-control custom-select">
                            <option selected="selected">--Select--</option>
                            <option value="2.4">2.4</option>
                            <option value="3.8">3.8</option>
                            <option value="7.3">7.3</option>
                            <option value="11.1">11.1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">AMSL(m) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAMSL" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label>Platform required <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="radio" name="Platform" value="YES" id="rbPltYes" />
                                Yes</label>
                            <label class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="radio" name="Platform" value="NO" id="rbPltNo" />
                                No</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label>Platform Height(m) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPlatformHeight" maxlength="10" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label>Rooftop Site  <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="radio" name="Rooftype" value="YES" id="rbRFSYes" />
                                Yes</label>
                            <label class="col-xs-6">
                                <input type="radio" name="Rooftype" value="NO" id="rbRFSNo" />
                                No</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 marginBottom">
                        <label>No of Floors in building</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNoofFloorsBldg" maxlength="10" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" disabled="disabled" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>In addition to standard space requirement for Roof top Site additional space 5 Mtr * 4 Mtr for VSAT Antenna. <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAddRoofTopSite" maxlength="50" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>
                            Structural Stability Certificate (SST)<br class="hidden-sm" />
                            from Local consultant <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" id="txtStructuralStability" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>Height of the Antenna from Ground [Mtrs] <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txthegtAntennaFromGrnd" maxlength="10" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>Satellite Band <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtSatelliteBand" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="antennaOrientation" class="tabPane">
            <h2>Antenna Orientation</h2>
            <div class="tabText clearfix">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>Azimuth Angle </label>
                        <%--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAzimuthAngle" maxlength="50" />--%>

                        <label>GSAT 16 (55° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAzimuth16" maxlength="10" />
                        <br />
                        <label>Azimuth Angle GSAT 18 (74° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAzimuth18" maxlength="10" />
                        <br />
                        <label>Azimuth Angle GSAT 12 (83° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAzimuth12" maxlength="10" />
                        <br />
                        <label>Azimuth Angle GSAT 17 (93.5° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAzimuth17" maxlength="10" />


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>Elevation Angle </label>
                        <%--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtElevationAngle" maxlength="50" />--%>
                        <label>GSAT 16 (55° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtElevation16" maxlength="10" />
                        <br />
                        <label>GSAT 18 (74° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtElevation18" maxlength="10" />
                        <br />
                        <label>GSAT 12 (83° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtElevation12" maxlength="10" />
                        <br />
                        <label>GSAT 17 (93.5° E) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtElevation17" maxlength="10" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>Distance to nearest airport (KM) <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtdistNearAirport" maxlength="10" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 marginBottom">
                        <label>Airport Name <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAirportName" maxlength="50" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>


<div class="formNavigation clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <a id="prevBtn" class="formbutt prev">Previous</a>
                <a id="nextBtn" class="formbutt next">Next</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

using `.addClass('classname')` method you can add class dynamically.

```
if(condition){
  $("#id").addClass('classname');
}
```

where `id` is the html element where you want to add class.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.next').on('click',function(){
var formfields=$("#siteDetails input:text, #siteDetails   input:radio,#siteDetails select");
var counter=0;
formfields.each(function(){
if($(this).val!=''){
counter=counter+1;
}
});
if(counter==formfields.length)
{
$('#antennaOrientation').addClass('completed ');
}
else{alert(' fill all fields');}
});
```

You have to use on() function to attach the required work to the click event , and addClass() to add the .completed to the second function you have to set a counter to be sure that all form filed is filled with the val property then if the counter equivalent to form fields add the class else do something like alert that not all form field is filled